# How can I copy the text of an unreportable error?

Tags: ppa, crash, apport, whoopsie

Occasionally I receive an error report from Ubuntu with the option to send in the details of the error. However, if the error was generated from a non-official package (local installation or PPA) I cannot just click submit to send in the error.

How can I copy all the error details so that I can manually submit them to the appropriate project?

Comment: That dialog should make its text copy-able. Please [vote here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1606712) for this feature.

Comment: @DanDascalescu - That bug seems to be a duplicate of [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/apport/+bug/1133184).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If apport has tried to collect the data from the crash, then look in

*/var/crash*

Alternatively you might look to see if there is a *-dbg* package for the application.

Try running the app from a terminal with -h - see if there is a debug option

Exaile for instance has a debug option, which can be run with

```
exaile --debug
```

Perhaps talk to whoever the application comes from.

Comment: `/var/crash` contained a useful file, but with much more info than in the splash screen ("Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error”).