# How to copy/paste from "Sorry, the application XXX has stopped unexpectedly"

Tags: crash, apport, usability

An app just crashed and I want to copy the error message and paste it into a search engine to hopefully find a solution.

Unfortunately the error dialog does not allow me to copy/paste anything:

[image: Sorry, the application XXX has stopped unexpectedly]

In particular the stack trace, which is very long. Typing manually is slow and unreliable.

Maybe the same details can be copied from somewhere else?

*Note: Similar to [How can I copy the text of an unreportable error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152914/how-can-i-copy-the-text-of-an-unreportable-error) but with more details. If one must be closed as a duplicate, despite being newer I believe this one is more useful. It is de-facto more popular: 200 views there, 42k views here.*

Comment: Have you tried middle clicking?  I used to run into this problem at my last job, but if I highlighted the text then switched over to a notepad app, middle clicking would simultaneously copy/paste in Ubuntu when nothing else would work.

Comment: There is the feature request for the text to be copy/paste-able. Please [vote here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/apport/+bug/1133184).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All crash report data can be found in the `.crash` files located in:

```
/var/crash
```

And as stated [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/1273752/comments/8):

```
When sent a .upload and .uploaded file is added.
It includes a CoreDump: base64 field that can be quite huge though.
```

Comment: Great simple and effective.

Comment: @DanDascalescu - That bug seems to be a duplicate of [this one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/apport/+bug/1133184).

Answer (score 5):

Nope, there is no way to copy/paste. You can "vote" for this issue to be fixed at:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/1273752
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/1606712